# Installing WebUI with proper Environmental Variables

Tags: ros, setup.bash

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to install the web interface on my laptop. I've gotten things to work after a little tweaking (which I updated on the wiki), so that I get through the whole installation process.

However, when I open a browser, I get this error message.

`MOD_PYTHON ERROR
ProcessId:      6630
Interpreter:    '127.0.0.1'
ServerName:     '127.0.0.1'
DocumentRoot:   '/var/www'
URI:            '/webui/'
Location:       '/webui/'
Directory:      None
Filename:       '/var/www/webui'
PathInfo:       '/'
Phase:          'PythonHandler'
Handler:        'startmod'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1537, in HandlerDispatch
default=default_handler, arg=req, silent=hlist.silent)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1229, in _process_target
result = _execute_target(config, req, object, arg)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1128, in _execute_target
result = object(arg)
File "/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/web_interface/webui/src/webui/startmod.py", line 18, in handler
ros_root = os.environ['ROS_ROOT']
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/UserDict.py", line 22, in getitem
raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'ROS_ROOT'`

Clearly, `ROS_ROOT` is not being set properly. Any ideas where to set this variable so that the Webui picks up on it? Currently, I believe it is being set through  `setup.bash`.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10703/installing-webui-with-proper-environmental-variables/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2011-07-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi David
I got it to work i had to stop apache from starting at boot after i launched webui from webui directory i could log on using localhost:9090
the web directory in in /tmp

peter

---

Originally posted by [Peter Heim](https://answers.ros.org/users/71/peter-heim/) with karma: 215 on 2011-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2011-07-24**:
Stopping apache and then relaunching the webui fixed the problem.